# How does this javascript object with parameters work?

Tags: javascript

I am working on someone else's code and I don't understand how this object works?

```
obj[fnName](param, param1)
```

I understand obj[fnName], but how can the object be passed values?

the full statment is `var res = obj[fnName](param, param1)`;

param and param1 can be an object or a string

If param or param1 is null then the statement is null

Comment: The value of `obj[fnName]` is a function…

Comment: it probably is a method of an object called with two arguments

Comment: `obj[fnName]` retrieves a property value from the object, and in your code that property value is expected to be a function. The subsequent values in parentheses then are the argument list of a function call to that function.

Comment: obj[fnName] is a function. Check it  typeof(obj[fnName])

Comment: what's wrong with this question why -3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are first class objects. You can treat them just like any other value. You can pass them around and you can assign them places, including to properties of other objects.

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = 1; // A number
obj.bar = "bar"; // A string
obj.baz = function baz (arg1, arg2) { console.log(arg2, arg1); }; // A function
obj.baz(obj.foo, obj.bar);
```

Answer (score 1):

obj[fnName] is referencing some function on the object, so you're getting that function and immediately calling it with two parameters.  For instance, if the object was:

```
obj = {
    myFunction: function (param1, param2) {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

Then doing `obj[myfunction]('hello', 'world')` would be the equivalent of doing something like this:

```
var theFunction = obj[myFunction]; // storing the function in a method
theFunction('hello', 'world'); // calling the function
```